# How to connect to RDP through proxy from Windows

Tags: remote-desktop, proxy

I need to connect to RDP through proxy-server.
I have HTTP and socks5 proxy available.

I have Windows 10. The target is a Windows server.

Comment: [Connecting to Remote Desktop using proxy and Remote Desktop Gateway?](https://serverfault.com/questions/608991/connecting-to-remote-desktop-using-proxy-and-remote-desktop-gateway)

Comment: [How to use RDP client through a proxy?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/67cff1e5-8418-49c7-8d96-9101727ae076/how-to-use-rdp-client-through-a-proxy-?forum=w7itpronetworking)